# Implementing custom OAuth2 login for ArcGIS Web AppBuilder developer?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-10.5, arcgis-web-appbuilder, authentication

I have a web mapping application on ArcGIS Web AppBuilder developer edition. I downloaded the app and published on IIS.

I want to validate users using OAuth2 like [IdentityServer](https://identityserver.io/), [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) or Facebook.

The proxy.config file contains some settings that used OAuth2.

```
<serverUrl url="http://route.arcgis.com"
    clientId="6Xo1d-example-9Kn2"
    clientSecret="5a5d50-example-c867b6efcf969bdcc6a2"
    rateLimit="600"
    rateLimitPeriod="60"
    matchAll="true">
</serverUrl>
```

Can I change these settings for use [IdentityServer](https://identityserver.io/) or Google auth?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We're trying to do the same thing.

Comment: No I did not figure out.